# Grass GIS table creation error during r.to.vect

Tags: grass-gis, error, vectorization

When I execute `r.to.vect` the following error appears:

```
r.to.vect input=sreviLC815109_-120_-120 output=temp feature=area --o --q
DBMI-DBF driver error:


ERROR: Unable to create table: create table temp ( cat integer, value
   double precision)
```

Any ideas what this could be?
My main issue is that this error appears absolutely sporadically in a script while the action is performed on many files. I could shift the error message a bit to a later point in time by deleting the `temp` vector map before, but it still appears. I am working with Grass 6.4.3.

EDIT:
When I do the action manually, everything works fine.

Comment: Do you see a change to update to GRASS GIS 7?